# Mysterious misbehavior of Selenium's .click()

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I was working on a web **scraper** and it was working fine when suddenly, I couldn't log in anymore and I was (and still) getting this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\path\daily.py", line 66, in <module>
    wait.until(presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'validBtnBlue')))
  File "C:\Users\me\path\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

After investigation, I found out that the click function is just getting ignored. I don't know why it happened nor how it's possible...I've tried with another button on the same page (`'a.registerButton.blueButton'`) and it worked ! Why does it refuse to click on this button

```py
URL = 'https://www.airlines-manager.com/'

with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options) as driver:
    def connect():
        driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys(email)
        print("username good")
        driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
        print("password good")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button#loginSubmit.blueButton')
        print("login button good")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button#loginSubmit.blueButton').click()
        print("click good")
    print("go to URL")
    driver.get(URL)
    print("gone to URL")
    print("will wait")
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    print("has waited")
    print("will connect")
    connect()
    print("passed connect")
    driver.get(URL_WHEEL_GAME)
```

`print` are here to check where the code has stopped

*I've check password and e-mail, they are good*

Comment: works fine for me.  I dont know the username/pw to enter so I just put 'test' but it got all the way down to the bottom and passed in all the print statements and then crashed at get(URL_WHEEL_GAME)

Comment: I've updated the question. I tested with another button and it work while it didn't with the login one

Comment: It is impossible for me to check this without a valid username/pw.  I enter dummy data and I get a "invalid identifier" pop up message, so I can't check if the connect button is working properly or not

Comment: Then it worked for you... It click and failed? Mine don't fail because it didn't click... It have tested on another machine and it work... What could make .click() to not click on a particular machine ?

Comment: Yea a black box pops up with "Echec de la connexion   Identifiants invalides", so i guess the click does work for me.  Not sure why it wouldnt for you.  Are you running a fresh chrome browser each run?

Comment: try removing the 'with' statement.  Just connect normally.  driver = WebDriver. Chrome(<parameters>) and then driver.get('https://www.airlines-manager.com/') etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem! When I edited the mail variable, I accidentally added a space at the end. I didn't care about it because when I login manually with a space at the end of the e-mail, it's working and I assume it would be the same with selenium. As time goes on, I did forget about it... It turns out thatt when it's selenium, the page a bug (it enter a strange stat where it's seems like the page is loading without really loading) and the button doesn't react. That's why I tought the .click didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me and resulted in the invalid login message:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.airlines-manager.com/')
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('test')
print("username good")
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('testemail')
print("password good")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button#loginSubmit.blueButton')
print("login button good")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button#loginSubmit.blueButton').click()
print("click good")
```